# Wallet import issues

Tags: wallet, private-key

I had saved 2 private keys starting with K and L respectively which is a 52 characters key along with address some small balances of $300 thought i lost them luckily it was saved in my gdrive But when i import the key to a electrum or other  wallets it shows a different address and not able to access the address with which it was generated for. Not sure what is the issue please help. So the key i have is in compressed wif format and i am trying to import it to electrum which uses derivation path - m/Oh (Bip32) so i tried converting compressed WIF to WIF and import to electrum but its showing a different address. As i remember taking the private key and the address correctly on a notepad before reinstalling windows few years back.

Comment: You can import the key to different derivation paths using Bitcoin Core.